# Not able to create instance of referenced class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just installed a package from NuGet in Visual Studio using C# Web API 4.7.2
and everything is working properly for me, but when I want to create an object of the imported library it comes to this error "cannot be initialized. It is not a field or property.".
Here is my code:

```
var payment = new PaymentDto { Iinn = "1131244211", Acn = "2131244212", Trmn = "3131244213", Trn = "4131244214" };
```

And, Here is the class from Package:

```
namespace TaxCollectData.Library.Dto.Content
{
    [NullableAttribute(0)]
    [NullableContextAttribute(1)]
    public class PaymentDto : IEquatable<PaymentDto>
    {
        public PaymentDto();
        protected PaymentDto(PaymentDto original);

        public long Pdt { get; set; }
        public string Pcn { get; set; }
        public string Trn { get; set; }
        public string Trmn { get; set; }
        public string Acn { get; set; }
        public string Iinn { get; set; }
        public string Pid { get; set; }
        protected virtual Type EqualityContract { get; }

        public virtual PaymentDto <Clone>$();
        [NullableContextAttribute(2)]
        public virtual bool Equals(PaymentDto? other);
        [NullableContextAttribute(2)]
        public override bool Equals(object? obj);
        public override int GetHashCode();
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public string get_Acn();
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public string get_Iinn();
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public string get_Pcn();
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public long get_Pdt();
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public string get_Pid();
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public string get_Trmn();
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public string get_Trn();
        public override string ToString();
        protected virtual bool PrintMembers(StringBuilder builder);

        [NullableContextAttribute(2)]
        public static bool operator ==(PaymentDto? left, PaymentDto? right);
        [NullableContextAttribute(2)]
        public static bool operator !=(PaymentDto? left, PaymentDto? right);
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked the code and reproduced it, there is no error in using object initializer in this code. can you share more parts of your code?

Comment: Usually the error message would contain the information *which* member could not be initialized.

Comment: It seems the `PaymentDto` class is in fact a `record` and thus needs C# 9.0 or higher to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with this package.
paymentDto is a record type.
you cannot inherit from it by a class.

Comment: you are right, it's a record type and record type is available in .NET 5 or higher.